# gem install eventmachineで失敗する

Tags: ruby, rubygems

お世話になります。

タイトルのとおりですが、gemのeventmachineをinstallしようとするとErrorが出てきてInstallができません...
いろいろ調べたのですが、結局解決できなかったので、ここに質問させていただきます。

なお、rubyのバージョンは2.4.0
開発環境はMacBookAirになります。

つぎに下記が実施ログとなります。

```
YourMacBookAir:slackTest userName$ gem install eventmachine
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/ext
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170407-37771-1h8lzrd.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... yes
checking for -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes

checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
CXXFLAGS=$(cxxflags)
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.4.0-static/eventmachine-1.2.3/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.4.0-static/eventmachine-1.2.3
/gem_make.out
```

次にg++とgccのバージョンをコマンドにて確認した結果になります。

```
YourMacBookAir:slackTest userName$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix


YourMacBookAir:slackTest userName$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

エラーメッセージに`make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory`とありましたので、g++あたりに問題があるのかと思いますが、具体的な解決方法がわからず困っております。

他に必要な情報や実行結果などありましたら、連絡いただければ記載いたします。

お手数ですが、解決策のわかる方ご教授いただければ助かります。

追記、質問に対してコマンドの実施結果になります。

```
YourMacBookAir:slackTest userName$ type g++-4.2
-bash: type: g++-4.2: not found
YourMacBookAir:slackTest userName$ type ruby
ruby is /Users/takatakentarou/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Comment: `type g++-4.2` と `type ruby` の結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: @nekketyuuu さん 結果を本文に載せさせていただきました。参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tone0929さんのMacにインストールされている`g++`はバージョン4.2.1のようなので、無理やり`g++-4.2`というファイルを`g++`への[シンボリックリンク](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF)として作成してやれば解決しそうです。

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.2
```

ただし`g++`のバージョンが上がってしまうとこれは正しくないので、注意してください。その場合はたとえば`g++-4.2`を独立したバイナリとして用意すると解決するでしょう(そのためにはg++の特定のバージョンをインストールする必要があるはずです)。

- 参考

  - ["getting eventmachine gem to compile on OSX Lion 10.8.2 with xcode 4.5.1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908484/getting-eventmachine-gem-to-compile-on-osx-lion-10-8-2-with-xcode-4-5-1) -- Stack Overflow
  - [「普段どうやってエラーメッセージから問題を解決しているか？」](http://nilfs.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/06/17/175246) …… 記事中で解説されているエラーが今回のものと同一です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一旦上記で解決いたしました。いまいまはこれで凌ぎますが、時間が出来次第、他の解決策も試させていただきます。　非常に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

(Tone0929さんの解決にはならないかもしれませんが、回答の集積を意識し、ここに書き残しておきます）

eventmachineのGitHub上のレポジトリで、OS X 10.11上で同じエラー`make: /usr/bin/g++-4.2: No such file or directory`を出しているissueを見つけました。

これによると、「古いOS Xの際にrbenv経由でインストールしたRubyが`g++-4.2`に依存していた。`.rbenv/`を消してRubyとgemを再インストールすると問題が解決した」そうです。

参考： ["Can't install on OS X 10.11"](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/677) -- GitHub